# Is ship turn rate still limited by the "viewport"? What ships turn faster if you "zoom out" in third person view?

Tags: allegiance

I know people hate flying in third person view in Allegiance: the ship is dead center on the screen and you can't see what you are hitting. This question is, however, about those moments when you aren't hitting anything (be it reloading or just travelling around) and tapping F11 might let you outmaneuver your enemy.

(Basically, the further you zoom in, the slower rotating your ship is. However, apparently, some ships can turn around so fast they were limited in the turn rate even when fully zoomed out.)

However, I think I recall this was one of the bugs fixed in R5 or R6, but I can't find it on the trac. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter how fast you spin around, if you are killing your momentum, you are making yourself a spinning/sitting target.

if you are not actively trying to shoot something, you should almost always be trying to keep your speed up.

see: "why mashing sidethrusters gets you killed faster"

EDIT: The ability to spin faster, is only useful to turn your ship around, turning your ship around in 3rd person view does not benefit you, because it is very hard to aim accurately.

also, even with a remapping of the control keys, the small delay between the zoom-in/zoom-out is going to add more confusion

Comment: I guess that's indeed a problem when you're not just flying in circles, after all.

Comment: the advantage of being zoomed out is being able to turn faster, turning faster kills your speed faster, making you more stationary, thus killed faster. There is no reason to zoom out, and less reason to recommend it to new players who are going to learn bad habits from it

Answer (score 2):

In R5, turn rate is still limited to 75 degrees per second. In R6, this limit has been removed for ships, although maximum turn rate in turrets is still 75 dps. This means that Rix now has a yaw rate of 90 dps. Also, since Dreg starts with a 75 dps turn rate, their agility upgrades will now increase their turn rate instead of just their torque. Roll rate was never capped.

-Compellor

Answer (score 0):

Work has been done in this area for R6.  http://trac.alleg.net/ticket/88

Try it out on Beta Wednesday!